# build a release with Rebar in a windows environment

Tags: erlang, rebar

I try to build an Erlang application release using Rebar.

I followed the tutorial from http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html.

I am working in a WindowsXP environment, using MINGW32 to support git, shell scripts, make, etc...

I got no problem to create the application, the node and the release; but when I want to start the application using the command

> "myapp console"

it fails because it can't find the command erlexec.

I changed in the "myapp script" the $CMD variable from ".../erlexec" to ".../erl.exe" which is the full name of the VM program in windows and it works.

I would like to avoid to modify all the entries of all the scripts - there are a lot of scripts with multiple entry point and I fear it will be re-written when I will build a next release.

Is there a config file to modify, or am I missing a step during generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple...

Just launch the command from dos environment, and it works.

In addition I rebuilt the rebar script first, from dos, but I don't know if it was necessary.